# Return to the activity main by clicking in a item of the navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments

Im working with an android app which have 3 fragments and the activity_main, all of them are listed in a navigation drawer. The question is how can i return to the activity main by clicking in a item of the navigation drawer.

The basic idea of waht I need is to close all the fragments open to return to the activity main

This is my code.

```
    if(id==R.id.taximetro){
    //this is my activity_main that i need to return   
        trans = true;
    } else if (id == R.id.factura) {
        fragment=new frmFactura();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        trans = true;
    } else if (id == R.id.dispBlue) {
        fragment=new frmDispositivos();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        trans = true;
    } else if (id == R.id.ayuda) {
        fragment=new frmAyuda();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        trans = true;
    } 
    if (trans) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, fragment).commit();
        item.setCheckable(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(item.getTitle());
    }
    //getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: please add the code for the navigation drawer adapter..?

Comment: You already are within the MainActivity... Fragments are within Activities.

Comment: Also, you have a lot of duplicate code here. For example, `if (trans) { }` you perform the `beginTransaction().replace` that you already did in all the other if-else statments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple like you call fragments ..call your `MainActivity`

if you want check whats available on the view,

keep an ENUM value or other related way ..and change the value related the the view that you loaded ,and check a fragment is loaded or still the main view exists in your `MainActivity` using that ENUM value in your MainActivity call

so,

if a fragment view is loaded recall your `MainActivity`
else just slide the navigation because you are already in the view of MainActivity without any fragment loaded on it

```
if(id==R.id.taximetro){
// call your activity again  if you want you can check that a fragment view is loaded  or not and do changes only when you need if there is a fragment view loaded.. or simply recall it 
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
 finish();
    }
```